# Keyerror:> in Python: Blackjack

Tags: python

I am trying to build an application of BlackJack using python. I am having a problem in the code as the keyerror:> in Python is coming.
My code is

```
  import simplegui
  import random

  # load card sprite - 936x384 - source: jfitz.com
  CARD_SIZE = (72, 96)
  CARD_CENTER = (36, 48)
  card_images = simplegui.load_image("http://storage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/cards_jfitz.png")

  CARD_BACK_SIZE = (72, 96)
  CARD_BACK_CENTER = (36, 48)
  card_back = simplegui.load_image("http://storage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/card_jfitz_back.png")    

  # initialize some useful global variables
  in_play = False
  outcome = ""
  score = 0

  # define globals for cards
  SUITS = ('C', 'S', 'H', 'D')
  RANKS = ('A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K')
  VALUES = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10}
  flag=False

  # define card class
  class Card:
      def __init__(self, suit, rank):
          if (suit in SUITS) and (rank in RANKS):
              self.suit = suit
              self.rank = rank
          else:
              self.suit = None
              self.rank = None
              print "Invalid card: ", suit, rank

      def __str__(self):
          return self.suit + self.rank

      def get_suit(self):
          return self.suit

      def get_rank(self):
          return self.rank

      def draw(self, canvas, pos):
          card_loc = (CARD_CENTER[0] + CARD_SIZE[0] * RANKS.index(self.rank), 
                      CARD_CENTER[1] + CARD_SIZE[1] * SUITS.index(self.suit))
          canvas.draw_image(card_images, card_loc, CARD_SIZE, [pos[0] + CARD_CENTER[0], pos[1] + CARD_CENTER[1]], CARD_SIZE)

  # define hand class
  class Hand:
      def __init__(self):
          c=list()
          self.h=c  # create Hand object

      def __str__(self):
           p=" "
           for i in xrange(len(self.h)):
              p+=str(self.h[i])
           return p
                  # return a string representation of a hand

      def add_card(self, card):
          self.h.append(card)   # add a card object to a hand

      def get_value(self):
          global flag
          last=0
          sum=0
          # count aces as 1, if the hand has an ace, then add 10 to hand value if it doesn't bust
          for i in xrange(len(self.h)):
              last+=1
              sum+=VALUES[str(self.h[i])[-1]]
              if(str(self.h[i])[-1]=='A'):
                  flag=True
              else:
                  flag=False

          if(flag):
              if(sum<=21):
                  sum+=10
              else:
                  sum+=1

          else:
              if(sum>21):
                  if(last == len(self.h)):
                      return sum
                  #else:
                      #sum=sum-VALUES[str(self.h[i])[-1]]

   # compute the value of the hand, see Blackjack video

      def draw(self, canvas, pos):
              # draw a hand on the canvas, use the draw method for cards
                  for i in xrange(len(self.h)):
                      card=Card(str(self.h[i]),VALUES[str(self.h[i])[-1]])
                      card.draw(canvas,[10+2*i,20])



  # define deck class 
  class Deck:
      def __init__(self):
          deck=[]
           # create a Deck object
          for i in xrange(len(SUITS)):
              for j in xrange(len(RANKS)):
                  k=Card(SUITS[i],RANKS[j])
                  deck.append(k)
          self.d=deck

      def shuffle(self):
          # shuffle the deck 
          random.shuffle(self.d)   # use random.shuffle()

      def deal_card(self):

               return random.choice(self.d)# deal a card object from the deck

      def __str__(self):
          o=" " # return a string representing the deck
          for i in xrange(len(self.d)):
              o+=str(self.d[i])
          return o






  #define event handlers for buttons
  def deal():
      global outcome, in_play
      d1=Deck()
      # your code goes here
      d1.shuffle()

      for i in xrange(4):
          player.add_card(d1.deal_card)
          dealer.add_card(d1.deal_card)

      in_play = True

  def hit():
          # replace with your code below
     global outcome,score,in_play
     if(player.get_value()<=21):
          player.add_card(d1.deal_card)
      # if the hand is in play, hit the player
     else:
          outcome+="You are busted"
          in_play=False
          score=score-1
      # if busted, assign a message to outcome, update in_play and score

  def stand():
          # replace with your code below

      global outcome,in_play,score
      if(not(in_play)): # if hand is in play, repeatedly hit dealer until his hand has value 17 or more
          outcome=" "
          outcome+="You are busted"
      else:
          while(dealer.get_value<=17):
              dealer.add_card(d1.deal_card)
          if(dealer.get_value>17):
              outcome=" "
              outcome+="The dealer busted"
          else:
              if(dealer.get_value>player.get_value):
                  outcome=" "
                  outcome+="Dealer wins"
                  score=score-1
              else:
                  outcome=" "
                  outcome+="Player wins"
                  score=score+1
      in_play=True
      # assign a message to outcome, update in_play and score

  # draw handler    
  def draw(canvas):
      # test to make sure that card.draw works, replace with your code below


      card=Card("S","A")  
      card.draw(canvas, [300, 300])
      canvas.draw_text(outcome,[150,100],20,"Blue")
      canvas.draw_text(str(score),[400,100],20,"Blue")

  # initialization frame
  frame = simplegui.create_frame("Blackjack", 600, 600)
  frame.set_canvas_background("Green")

  #create buttons and canvas callback
  frame.add_button("Deal", deal, 200)
  frame.add_button("Hit",  hit, 200)
  frame.add_button("Stand", stand, 200)
  frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

  player=Hand()
  dealer=Hand()

  # get things rolling
  deal()
      frame.start()
```

In the get_value function I am getting the error of Keyerror:> in python on line 72. Please help.

Comment: A `KeyError` means that a key doesn't exist, ie.: `{}['nonexitent']` ... The error also prints *which* key doesn't exist, and a backtrace (with line numbers), neither of which you posted...

Comment: Key Error: > is coming on line no 72

Comment: You are setting `self.h=c` in `Hand.__init__`, but what is `c`?

Comment: You're chaining three index operations on line 72, so it's hard to see which is causing the error. Use a set of output statements on the line before for the things you're using, e.g.: `print VALUES; print self.h[i]`. Otherwise you might consider splitting line 72 into several statements to make it easier to debug.

Comment: I am not getting any item in self.h list can u tell me the mistake please help

Comment: Ok I have solved the problem